# Date Filter by Cell Reference in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dynamic range of points of data that I would like to add a date filter by a cell reference and seem to be getting a 'parse error'. I have compared to a sheet that I have built out and seems to be in the exact same format.

This one I have an error

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A:B")"select Col1, Col2 where Col2 > date'"&TEXT(H1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Where as this one below works perfectly fine for my other sheet.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL2","Sheet2!A1:Y"),"select Col1, Col11, Col13, Col6, Col16,Col3,Col20 where Col3 > date'"&TEXT(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'order by Col3 ASC")
```

H1 is a reference for the past 30 days dynamically so there is no need to manually update this date every day.

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL2","Sheet2!A1:Y"),"select Col1, Col11, Col13, Col6, Col16,Col3,Col20 where Col3 > date'"&TEXT(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by Col3 ASC")
```

with a space before order by